# PowerShell Parameter only in Get-Help

Tags: powershell, helper

When I run `get-help get-process -detailed` I get the full help.  What would I run if I just wanted to know what the `get-process -id` parameter does?  Is there a way to drill down like that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

yes, use the -Parameter flag

```
> Get-Help Get-Process -Parameter id
```

The parameter flag can also use wildcards. To see help on all parameters

```
> Get-Help Get-Process -Parameter *
```

Just so you're aware you can do a Get-Help on Get-Help.

```
> Get-Help Get-Help -detailed
```

Hope that helps